# I want to cache static frequently used content on disk

Tags: nginx, caching, networking, dns, varnish

We are going to deploy a storage server without raid ( we have lots of data but limited storage for now | data is not important ), so we will assign a subdomain to each of 12 x 8 TB drives for our clients to download from it.

Clients will be downloading content through a static URL over http (http://subdomain1.xyzwebsite.com/folder1/file1.mkv), our server is powerful with 128 GB of RAM and 6 x 2 Cores Processor with 10 Gigabit LAN Card but without RAID when multiple clients download from same drive it will look like a bottleneck so to overcome it I started to look into varnish cache but i do not get a satisfaction how will it serve data (I do not understand setting object size and manually setting cache location to RAM or DISK).

NOTE: each file size can range from 500 MB to 4 GB

We do not want a separate server for caching data, we want to utilize this powerful server to do this, now for the solution i think that data is located in a 1 drive and if it is possible to copy/mirror/cache frequent used (files download in 24 hours or 12 hours) content to second drive and serve same file with same sub-domain

NOTE: Nginx know which file is accessed via access.log

scenerio:
there are 12 drives (there are 2 separate drives for os which i'm not counting here), i will store data on 11 drives and use 12th drive as a copy/mirror/cache for all drives, i know how http works whether i add multiple ip to same domain i can only download from one ip at a time ( i will add multiple ip address on same server ), this is my solution data will be served via round-robin, if one client is downloading from one ip another client might get to download from second ip.

Now i dont know how to implement it, i tried searching for solutions but i do not get any, there are two main problems:

1. how to copy/mirror/cache only frequent data of the 11 drives to 1 drive and serve from it
2. If i add second ip address entry to same subdomain and there is no data on 12th drive how will it fetch it

Nginx or Varnish based solution is required on same server, if RAM based cache can be done it will be good to

Answer (score 0):

Varnish can be used for this, but unfortunately not the open source version.

Varnish Enteprise features the so-called [Massive Storage Engine](https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/features/mse/), which uses both disk and RAM to store large volumes of data.

Instead of using files to store objects, MSE uses pre-allocated large files with filesystem-like behavior. This is much faster and less prone to disk fragmentation.

In MSE you can configure how individual disks should behave and how much storage per disk is used. Each disk or group of disks can be tagged.

Based on Varnish Enterprise's [MSE VMOD](https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/mse/), you can then control what content is stored on each disk or group of disks.

You can decide how content is distributed to disk based on content type, URL, content size, disk usage and many other parameters. You can also choose not to persist content on disk, but just keep content in memory.

Regardless of this MSE VMOD, "hot content" will be automatically buffered from disk into memory. There are also "waterlevel" settings you can tune do decide how to automatically ensure that enough space is always available.